# removing specific value in array of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with `6` keys from 1 to 6. each element of the corresponding key is an array of different sizes `(n,6)`. now I have the index of an element of the array to remove. suppose I want to remove element `150` of the array related to key `6`. I used this code:

```
del clusters[1][150]
*** ValueError: cannot delete array elements
```

but it could not work. could you please tell me how can I remove elements from a dictionary?
Thanks

the `clusters` variable is a `dict` as following image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You wrote
`del clusters[1][150]` but mentioned key `6`,
so you apparently intended
`del clusters[6][150]`. I will go with that.

Use:

```
arr = clusters[6]
assert arr.shape == (217, 6)
np.delete(arr, 150, 0)
assert clusters[6].shape == (216, 6)
```

cf https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html